# Liferay 7.3 - Auto upgrade of custom services

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have a custom service module (myproject-service & myproject-api).

With Liferay 7.2 and previous versions, when I changed my database model (for exemple : add a new column in a table in the service.xml), I used an **UpgradeProcess** and an **UpgradeStepRegistrator**, with an incrementation of the **Liferay-Require-SchemaVersion**.

Since the 7.3 version, the autoupgrade has been moved to a property and changed to false value. In developpement, this value is true and everything works fine but in production, my custom service doesn't upgrade now at server start.

Is there a solution to make this system works again automatically ? I've seen that now we have to do the upgrade manually in the gogo shell with upgrade:execute command.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for

```
Set this to true to execute the upgrade process when the portal starts and modules are activated.

upgrade.database.auto.run=false
```

You still need to build the "upgradeProcess", as in:
https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018162851-Creating-Data-Upgrade-Processes-for-Modules-

Comment: This property (with a true value) is not recommanded in production environments.

Comment: @DyM being recommended in production or not is simply the case for general deployments. If you find a stable environment where only your modules will be installed after testing.. well, it becomes just your call.. another thing is that the process will be dictated by your upgrade process and the risk associated with the ecucution in gogo shell will be the same, as the code will run anyway, as defined by your component. The question is about automatically executing what you do in gogo shell.

Comment: About your comment in the other answer: no, you do not leave the upgradeProcess aside, you should build it. And if you do not want that property, then use gogo shell or the upgrade tool that comes with your bundle.

Comment: In any case.. use your judgement, all options are there for you to decide.. some cases as just a minor table being created is safe in all options.. other cases, not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you *could* activate the same property in production systems. However, this is neither safe, nor performant: The solution for table updates is generic and (as far as I know) will

1. export your table's data,
2. DROP TABLE,
3. CREATE TABLE (with the new structure)
4. populate the table with the previously saved data.

Now, apart from this being horribly slow for large amounts of data, there are some other shortcomings:

- if you have *renamed* a column, or
- added a non-nullable column,

this would fail to do the work as you expected it (even in development).

Further:

- If this process is interrupted at any time, you might lose all of your data

In many cases, a simple `ALTER TABLE xxx ADD COLUMN yyy` would be sufficient, and is quick, safe and easy to do within SQL. That's where your UpgradeProcess kicks in. You wouldn't want to do that after every little bit in development (hence the property), but you certainly don't want to DROP TABLE with important data in production, and wait for who-knows-how-long, when there was just a trivial change.

From that point of view: You *want* to write a custom UpgradeProcess, even if you don't know that you do. And there's even [a great starting point](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/building-in-upgrade-support#database-upgrades), that takes away the repetitive and low level work.

Comment: ok, so now I leave these "upgradeProcess" aside and I execute my queries manually in the database directly before starting and deploying the modules. Is it this ?

Comment: if you want ServiceBuilder to take care of your database & persistence layer, I'd write the upgrade process. If you point it to existing tables to start with, I'd say you're free to choose. Of course, you're free to choose either way, but you'd need to update the release status as well if ServiceBuilder is in charge of maintaining your tables (watch out for the Release table or rather a similarly named service